# Change the WPF Ribbon Title in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, ribboncontrolslibrary

I haven following ribbon code

```
<ribbon:Ribbon Name="PMARibbon" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ribbon:Ribbon.TitleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Name="PMARibbonHeader" TextAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="Application Name" >
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ribbon:Ribbon.TitleTemplate>
</ribbon:Ribbon>
```

Now in c#, I can access PMARibbon, but I can't access PMARibbonHeader in c#.
How can do like below

```
PMARibbon.PMARibbonHeader.Text = "sample title"
```

I found that controls under data template could not be accessed directly.
I refereed the article for accesssing controls under DataTemplate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579(v=vs.110).aspx
But not sure how to apply this in my case ?
Could anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just use the `RibbonWindow.Title` property instead:

```
RibbonWindow.Title = "sample title";
```

From the [`Ribbon.Title` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon.title%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> You will typically set the Title property on the RibbonWindow instead of setting the Ribbon.Title property.
>
> The Ribbon.Title is shown in the title bar of the RibbonWindow if the Window.Title property of the RibbonWindow is null. If the Window.Title property is not null, the RibbonWindow title is shown instead of the Ribbon.Title value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but unfortunately, we are not using RibbonWindow. We are using existing Window and under it we have Ribbon control.

Comment: So likewise, can you not just use the `Window.Title` property instead?

Comment: Yes.. I can do that.. But my current case is different, in window there is Ribboncontrol whose title should be changed.

Comment: @Banng did you find a way for this?